# Will taking antihistamines increase someone's risk of getting ill?

Tags: infectious-diseases, immunosuppressant

If people take antihistamines, I suppose their immune system becomes suppressed (it needs histamines to work properly). If their immune system becomes suppressed, their body will react suboptimal to infections. Does that make them more or less likely to get ill?